# Problema com a opção de verificar pessoa existente na fila encadeada no Python

Tags: python

Meu código está com problema de **verificar a existência do nome de uma pessoa que já está inserida na lista**, quando eu insiro a pessoa na lista funciona perfeitamente, quando eu busco pelo nome quando a lista está vazia funciona perfeitamente, mas quando eu faço a verificação para saber se o nome está ali dá o seguinte erro:

```
ERROR:

elif pesquisar_pessoa.nome == "":

AttributeError: 'Pessoa' object has no attribute 'nome'
```

Meu código está aqui (eu marquei as linhas específicas do código)

```
# Código de fila
class Fila:
    inicio = None
    fim = None

class Pessoa:
    nome: str
    idade: int
    peso: float
    genero: str
    proximo = None

def inserir_elemento(fila, pessoa):
    if fila_vazia(fila) == True:
        fila.inicio = pessoa
        fila.fim = pessoa
    else:
        fila.fim.proximo = pessoa
        fila.fim = pessoa
    print(f"Elemento {pessoa.nome} foi inserido\n")

def excluir_elemento(fila):
    if fila_vazia(fila) == True:
        print("A fila está vazia")
    else:
        elemento_excluido = fila.inicio
        proximo_fila = fila.inicio.proximo
        del fila.inicio
        fila.inicio = proximo_fila
        if fila.inicio == None:
            fila.fim = None
        print(f"O elemento {elemento_excluido.nome} foi excluído\n")

def fila_vazia(fila):
    verificar_fila = (fila.inicio == None and fila.fim == None)
    return verificar_fila

def tamanho_fila(fila):
    if fila_vazia(fila) == True:
        return 0
    else:
        contador_fila = 0
        ver_pessoa = fila.inicio
        while ver_pessoa != None:
            contador_fila += 1
            ver_pessoa = ver_pessoa.proximo
        return contador_fila

def imprimir_elemento(fila):
    if fila_vazia(fila) == True:
        print("A fila está vazia\n")
    else:
        ver_pessoa = fila.inicio
        while ver_pessoa != None:
            print(ver_pessoa.nome, ver_pessoa.idade, ver_pessoa.peso, 
            ver_pessoa.genero, end=" " if ver_pessoa.proximo != None else print())                                                          
            ver_pessoa = ver_pessoa.proximo                       
___________________________________________________________________
| def procurar_pessoa(fila, pesquisar_pessoa):                    |
|    if fila_vazia(fila) == True:                                         |
|        print("A fila está vazia para procurar alguém\n")        |
|    elif pesquisar_pessoa.nome == "":                            |
|        print ("Digite o nome da pessoa que deseja encontrar: ") |
|    else:                                                        |
|        ver_pessoa = fila.inicio                                 |
|        busca = ""                                               |
|       pessoa_encontrada = False                                 |
|        while ver_pessoa != None:                                |
|            if ver_pessoa.nome == pesquisar_pessoa.nome:         |
|                busca += ver_pessoa.nome + "Pessoa encontrada\n" |
|                pessoa_encontrada = True                         |
|            else:                                                |
|                busca += pesquisar_pessoa.nome + "\n"            |
|            if ver_pessoa.proximo != None:                       |
|                busca += ("\n")                                  |
|            ver_pessoa = ver_pessoa.proximo                      |
|                                                                 |
|        if pessoa_encontrada:                                    | 
|            print(busca)                                         | 
|        else:                                                    | 
|            print("Pessoa não encontrada")                       |
___________________________________________________________________

fila_encadeada = Fila()
opcao = 1
while opcao != 7:
    print ("1 - Inserir")
    print ("2 - Excluir")
    print ("3 - Imprimir")
    print ("4 - Informar tamanho da fila")
    print ("5 - Informar se a fila está vazia")
    print ("6 - Procurar nome da pessoa")
    print ("7 - Sair")
    opcao = int(input("Informe a opção: "))
    if opcao == 1:
        nome_informado = str(input("Informe o nome da pessoa: "))
        idade_informada = int(input("Informe a idade de {}: ".format(nome_informado)))
        peso_informado = float(input("Informe o peso de {}: ".format(nome_informado)))
        genero_informado = str(input("Informe o gênero de {}: ".format(nome_informado)))
        novo_elemento = Pessoa()
        novo_elemento.nome = nome_informado
        novo_elemento.idade = idade_informada
        novo_elemento.peso = peso_informado
        novo_elemento.genero = genero_informado
        inserir_elemento(fila_encadeada, novo_elemento)
    elif opcao == 2:
        excluir_elemento(fila_encadeada)
    elif opcao == 3:
        imprimir_elemento(fila_encadeada)
    elif opcao == 4:
        print(f"Tamanho da Fila: {tamanho_fila(fila_encadeada)}\n")
    elif opcao == 5:
        if(fila_vazia(fila_encadeada) == True):
            print(f"A fila está vazia\n")
        else:
            print(f"A fila não está vazia e possui {tamanho_fila(fila_encadeada)} elemento(s)\n")
_________________________________________________________________________
|    elif opcao == 6:                                                    |
|        pesquisar_pessoa = Pessoa()                                     |
|        pesquisar_pessoa.proximo = input("Digite o nome da pessoa: ")   |
|        procurar_pessoa(fila_encadeada, pesquisar_pessoa)               |
__________________________________________________________________________
    elif opcao == 7:
        print("Saindo...\n")
    else:
        print("Opção inválida, digite uma opção válida no menu\n")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex pelo que me parece você está passando um objeto com o atributo `nome` vazio sendo assim ele não existe e você está realizando uma comparação `elif pesquisar_pessoa.nome == ""`.

Basta corrigir a terceira linha do do código e trocar o atributo `próximo` pelo atributo `nome`, como mostrado abaixo:

```
elif opcao == 6:                                                    
    pesquisar_pessoa = Pessoa()                                     
    ->pesquisar_pessoa.nome = input("Digite o nome da pessoa: ")  
    print(type(pesquisar_pessoa))
    procurar_pessoa(fila_encadeada, pesquisar_pessoa)
```

Comment: No caso teria que retirar `elif pesquisar_pessoa.nome == "":                            
        print ("Digite o nome da pessoa que deseja encontrar: ")` pra colocar esse trecho de código?

Comment: você pose colocar  ele encadeado antes do `elif pesquisar_pessoa.nome == "": print ("Digite o nome da pessoa que deseja encontrar: ")` editei a resposta pra mostra como você pode inserir no seu código

Comment: `Invalid Syntax : elif pesquisar_pessoa not is Pessoa:`

Comment: @AlexF. analisei seu código mais a fundo, a propriedade `nome` não está preenchida no `pesquisar_pessoa` sendo assim ele ainda não existe no objeto, seu programa funcionará quando você trocar `pesquisar_pessoa.proximo` por `pesquisar_pessoa.nome =  input('...`. Pode retirar o If que eu propus anteriormente

Comment: deu um Crtl + F e `ver_pessoa.proximo` existem 5 deles no código, especifique melhor onde devo mudar.

Comment: @AlexF. confira a resposta acima, marquei qual linha você deve alterar

Comment: O erro ainda está no `elif pesquisar_pessoa not is Pessoa:
                               
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @AlexF. pode remover esse if que eu indiquei, e seu código deve funcionar agora

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado @KilldaryAguiardeSantana.

Comment: @AlexF. estamos aqui pra ajudar, marque a resposta como certa